# Stretching containers (i need it to cap at a certain width/height

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm working on a little project and i completed the mobile version, now when i try to do the desktop version it stretches so much that my logo eats up the entire screen. and everythinggg is sooo bigg, i never had this problem idk why is just randomly came up.(the px are big numbers because in the mobile version everything is small)

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/Angel%20Garcia/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML%20CSS%20practice%20along/img/bg-mobile.png);
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    font-family: Raleway;
}
.fylo-con{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 460px;
    width: 865px;
    background-color: hsl(228, 56%, 26%);
    /*padding: 150px;*/
    border-top-right-radius: 300px;
    margin:150px 30px 10px 55px ;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}
.fylo-logo{
    height: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.fylo-img{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: auto;
}
.first-img{
    height: 56px;
    padding: 23px 25px;
    background-color: hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.second-img{
    height: 40px;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    background-color: hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 55px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.third-img{
    height: 40px;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    background-color: hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.second-con{
    background-color: hsl(228, 56%, 26%);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 380px;
    width: 865px;
    background-color: hsl(228, 56%, 26%);
    margin: 30px 30px 10px 55px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.second-p{
    margin-top: 55px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.progress-p{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-right:470px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.progress-p2{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#progress{
    background-color:hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 74%;
    margin-left: 105px;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
#progress>div{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,hsl(6, 100%, 80%), hsl(335, 100%, 65%));
    width: 75%;
    padding: 18px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.white-box{
  position:relative;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 170px;
  width: 420px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: 39px;
  margin-left: 203px;
}
.number{
  font-size: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.gbleft{
    position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 67px;
  right: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px){

  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="fylo-con">
    <img class="fylo-logo" src="file:///C:/Users/Angel%20Garcia/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML%20CSS%20practice%20along/img/logo.svg">
    <div class="fylo-img"> 
        <img class="first-img" src="file:///C:/Users/Angel%20Garcia/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML%20CSS%20practice%20along/img/icon-document.svg">
        <img class="second-img" src="file:///C:/Users/Angel%20Garcia/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML%20CSS%20practice%20along/img/icon-folder.svg">
        <img class="third-img" src="file:///C:/Users/Angel%20Garcia/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML%20CSS%20practice%20along/img/icon-upload.svg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="second-con">
    <p class="second-p">You've used 815 GB of your storage</p>
    <div id="progress">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <p class="progress-p">0 GB</p>
    <p class="progress-p2">1000 GB</p>
  <div class="white-box">
    <p class="number">185</p>
    <p class="gbleft">GB LEFT</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please include your whole code, and fix your formatting. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your viewport for everything on mobile to go smaller. You can add this meta tag right before the `</head>` of your page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will scale-up everything on mobile.

You can then add a max-width to your elements with the `max-width` CSS to your logo. Something like:

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/512" style="width: 100%; max-width: 512px;">
</div>
```

You can also use `max-height` if you would prefer to cap the height.

You could implement it into your code with something like:

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/Angel%20Garcia/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML%20CSS%20practice%20along/img/bg-mobile.png);
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    font-family: Raleway;
}
.fylo-con{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 460px;
    width: 865px;
    background-color: hsl(228, 56%, 26%);
    /*padding: 150px;*/
    border-top-right-radius: 300px;
    margin:150px 30px 10px 55px ;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}
.fylo-logo{
    /* remove this
    
    height: 90px;
    
    */
    
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    
    /* MAXWIDTH START*/
    
    max-width: 200px;
    
    /* MAXWIDTH END */
}
.fylo-img{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: auto;
}
.first-img{
    height: 56px;
    padding: 23px 25px;
    background-color: hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.second-img{
    height: 40px;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    background-color: hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 55px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.third-img{
    height: 40px;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    background-color: hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.second-con{
    background-color: hsl(228, 56%, 26%);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 380px;
    width: 865px;
    background-color: hsl(228, 56%, 26%);
    margin: 30px 30px 10px 55px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.second-p{
    margin-top: 55px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.progress-p{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-right:470px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.progress-p2{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#progress{
    background-color:hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 74%;
    margin-left: 105px;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
#progress>div{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,hsl(6, 100%, 80%), hsl(335, 100%, 65%));
    width: 75%;
    padding: 18px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.white-box{
  position:relative;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 170px;
  width: 420px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: 39px;
  margin-left: 203px;
}
.number{
  font-size: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.gbleft{
    position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 67px;
  right: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px){

  }
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fylo-con">
    <img class="fylo-logo" src="file:///C:/Users/Angel%20Garcia/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML%20CSS%20practice%20along/img/logo.svg">
    <div class="fylo-img"> 
        <img class="first-img" src="file:///C:/Users/Angel%20Garcia/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML%20CSS%20practice%20along/img/icon-document.svg">
        <img class="second-img" src="file:///C:/Users/Angel%20Garcia/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML%20CSS%20practice%20along/img/icon-folder.svg">
        <img class="third-img" src="file:///C:/Users/Angel%20Garcia/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML%20CSS%20practice%20along/img/icon-upload.svg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="second-con">
    <p class="second-p">You've used 815 GB of your storage</p>
    <div id="progress">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <p class="progress-p">0 GB</p>
    <p class="progress-p2">1000 GB</p>
  <div class="white-box">
    <p class="number">185</p>
    <p class="gbleft">GB LEFT</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

That will then cap your logo's maximum width to the value specified, in this case, 200 pixels.

More information:

Viewport:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)
[webdev](https://web.dev/responsive-web-design-basics/)

Max-width:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)
[devdocs](https://devdocs.io/css/max-width)